# Rabbitmq: How can fifo nature of rabbitmq be maintained with multiple consumers?

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

We have multiple consumer to handle create/update/delete request of stock.

All these request are processed in rabbitmq. The problem is that sometimes when stock is created and gets deleted immediately, the "delete" message is processed first and the "create" message later.

Although we push "create" message before "delete". This occurs as we have multiple consumers running on different servers.

My question is that running this with multiple consumers itself violates FIFO principle of queue. How can this be avoided?

Answer (score 1):

Assumption prior to proposal, the possible order of events for your stocks are:

1. create
2. update (optional, can be multiple)
3. delete

As [message priority](https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html) won't help in extreme cases like the one you describe,

I believe your best bet would be [delayed messages](https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2015/04/16/scheduling-messages-with-rabbitmq/), be it with the plugin referenced in the link, or through message TTLs and alternate exchange configuration.

Would propose you configure something along the lines of:

- delete messages with 200ms delay
- update messages with 100ms delay
- create messages with no delay

And also configure **don't allow prefetch** for the consumers.

Timings proposed would have to be adapted with actual processing time for each type of events.

But it's clear that proposal is definitely breaking the FIFO principle.

If you truly want to maintain FIFO, don't think you have any choice apart from single consumer (configuring exclusive consumption if you want backup processes "waiting" for the opportunity to consume)